# How to flip brush in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

How do I flip brush in Gimp? There is a option to **rotate**. But I want to flip Brush horizontally/vertically. Also is there any way to set keyboard shortcut for rotating brush while using it with tool(Not in brush editor) in gimp-2.10

Comment: There's nothing like that in GIMP, but if it's a gbr brush, you could open the gbr file and flip it, then save a copy with a file name back in your brushes folder.  That way you will have two versions of the one brush.

Comment: Thanks! That is one way to do. I need to have it while using with tools for most brushes. So that I can use alternatively just by flipping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no way to flip non-parametric brushes.**

The brush rotate options are only available on the "parametric" brushes (those that you can create with the brush editor). Since all these brushes have a symmetry you can achieve a flip by the suitable rotation.

**There is no way to set keyboard shortcut to rotate non-parametric brushes.**

You can set keyboard shortcuts to rotate the brush in `Edit>Preferences>Keyboard shortcuts` (look for `context-brush-angle`), but as said above this only applies to parametric brushes.

If you are using a "bitmap" brush, a work around is to open the brush as an image, and copy it to the clipboard, and use the`Clipboard` brush (first in the list of brushes, or top left corner in the grid). When you need to alter the brush, flip/rotate it in the brush image using the regular tool and copy the result to the clipboard.

Also, remember that you can have the brush (parametric or not) rotate along the direction of the stroke using the proper dynamics (`Track direction` for instance).

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late but in the angle part of the paintbrush options, set it to -90 or -180 depending on whether you want it flipped vertically or horizontally

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting workaround, recently suggested on Reddit:

https://www.reddit.com/r/GIMP/comments/d26h3h/how_to_flip_a_brush/

In short:

- Lock the brush to the view in the Paint tool options
- Flip the view temporarily

While this is effectively a flipped brush painting on your image, the downside is that this flips your image on-screen and may make it hard to paint exactly what you wanted.